# Xamarin Android iOS FirebasePushNotificationPlugin not receive message but token receves

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm using xamarin iOS FirebasePushNotificationPlugin for cloud messages, but i'm receiving the token but i can not receive any notification. `CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived` even not firing.

here is how my appDelegate looks likes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using Plugin.FirebasePushNotification;
using UIKit;

namespace onlinefirebase.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

            LoadApplication(new App());
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.CurrentNotificationPresentationOption =
         UserNotifications.UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert |
         UserNotifications.UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Badge;
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);
        }

        public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.RemoteNotificationRegistrationFailed(error);

        }
        // To receive notifications in foregroung on iOS 9 and below.
        // To receive notifications in background in any iOS version
        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
            // this callback will not be fired 'till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

            // If you disable method swizzling, you'll need to call this method. 
            // This lets FCM track message delivery and analytics, which is performed
            // automatically with method swizzling enabled.
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            // Do your magic to handle the notification data
            System.Console.WriteLine(userInfo);

            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how i receive the notification

```
using System;
using Plugin.FirebasePushNotification;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace onlinefirebase
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();


            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TOKEN : {p.Token}");
            };

            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received");
            };


        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I have verified

. Enabled Background Mode -> Remote Notifications
. Info.plist -> "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" boolean -> No

I'm successfully getting the token, but i can not receive the notification.

Comment: Did you add GoogleService-Info.plist to iOS project and make sure build action is BundleResource. Adding FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled in the app’s Info.plist file and set it to No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is based on Apple key, apple key should be upload to firebase cloud panel and it'll work